# Placing Number In A Range With An Increment

Tags: swift, xcode, math, numbers

In my Xcode project I am counting objects. The count can be from 1 to over 10,000. I would like to print out the count in a string that states its range in an increment of 10. I am still choosing the right increment, but I know it will be between 10 - 50, so the solution should have a configurable increment. How would I go about this?

**Example:**

- number: 15, range "10 to 20"
- number: 987, range "980 to 990"
- number: 146, range "140 to 150"

Comment: The question is kind of unclear, what's the input and what's the required output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to paste this into playground

```
func rangeInString(number: Int) -> String {

let reminder = number % 10
let lowerNumber = number - reminder
let higherNumber = lowerNumber + 10

let text = "number: \(number), range \"\(lowerNumber) to \(higherNumber)\""

return text}
```

Then call it like this:

```
print(rangeInString(number: 15))
```

Note: This will not work for negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
func range(_ value: Int) -> String {
    let lowerBound = Int(floor(Double(value)/10) * 10)
    return "\(lowerBound) to \(lowerBound+10)"
}

print(range(11))    // "10 to 20"
print(range(-11))   // "-20 to -10"
```